# Bootstrap 3 not working as responsive in my play framework?

Tags: html, css, playframework, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why my Bootstrap 3 is not working as responsive in my play framework?
This is my head contain of main.scala.html which use every where..

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/intlTelInput.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/icon.jpeg")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes()'></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: what exactly not working? describe your issue more specifically with html markup too?

Comment: I am using bootstrap3 with play.my web app view is great when it is open on full default window size browser.but when i resize the window the view is not view as in default window.So tell me one thing is this responsive or not ?